# How to detect dynamically if SSO is enabled on Mozilla / Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, single-sign-on, mozilla, ntlm

How to detect dynamically (maybe by javascript) if SSO is enabled on Mozilla / Chrome? Or any tricks to detect if the window prompt'll appear during the request?  This article http://www.salmanq.com/blog/how-to-check-if-integrated-windows-authentication-is-available/2011/03/  helps to fix the issue on IE. But how to fix that for Mozilla / Chrome?

In my case, if the window prompt is required (SSO is disabled) I want to show a form view, else I want to redirect to that url

Comment: By coding. What have you tried? @Inga

Comment: @Dhanuka I tried to use XMLHttpRequest. But seems that's impossible. Tried to read firefox network.settings of about:config entries by javascript, but didn't find anything

Comment: @Dhanuka https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=988

Answer (score 0):

i think there is no way to detect if the user used the prompt or enabled SSO. On serverside both ways will look the same and its somehow something you wouldnt want internet-sites to be able to do - reading client configs ...
I managed an intranet-site with SSO - if the user could not be authenticated he was redirected - and thats it.